# Draw Rzslider Based on current time duration in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date

I am implementing timepicker based on the date and after that select the time.
Right now slider draw the perfectly for the static time.
 **See the example:**

```js
var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  $scope.$watch('dateBirth', function(n, o) {
    var middleDay = n || new Date();
    middleDay.setHours(12);
    $scope.selectedDate = moment(middleDay);
    $scope.init();
  });
  
  $scope.init = function() {
    var startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime;
    
    var timeData = getRange($scope.selectedDate);
    $scope.localTime = timeData.currentTime; // actually start of this hour
    
    var arr = timeData.times.map(n => {
      return {
        value: n.value
        //legend: n.value
      };
    });
    
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.slider = {
        minValue: $scope.localTime.clone().subtract(4, "hours").format('YYYY DD MMM HH:mm'),
        maxValue: $scope.localTime.clone().add(4, "hours").format('YYYY DD MMM HH:mm'),
        options: {
          showTicks: true,
          stepsArray: arr,
          draggableRange: true,
        }
      };
    });
  }
  
  $scope.init();
});

function getRange(currentDate) {
  var arr = [];
  var totalHourRange = 32;
  var currentTime = currentDate || moment(); // current date and time using Moment
  
  // set current time to beginning of the hour
  currentTime.minute(0);
  
  // clone date and substract 1/2 total range to get start point
var tmpTime = currentTime.clone();
     tmpTime.subtract(totalHourRange / 2, 'hours');
  
  // offset is the number of minutes from the current point
  for (var i = -6 * (totalHourRange / 2); i <= 6 * (totalHourRange / 2); i++) {
      arr.push({value: tmpTime.format('YYYY DD MMM HH:mm'), offset: i * 10});
      tmpTime.add(10, 'minutes');
    }
  return { times: arr, currentTime: currentTime, totalHourRange: totalHourRange };
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="rzSliderDemo">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h2>AngularJS Touch Slider</h2>
    </header>
    <article>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="choos-birth" class="control-label">choose date:</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input id="choos-birth" class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="dateBirth" style="witdh:100px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <h4>Local time (beginning of the hour): <em>{{localTime.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a')}}</em></h4>
      <br /> Model:
      <input type="text" ng-model="slider.minValue" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="slider.maxValue" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.minValue" rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue" rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
Because of this middleDay.setHours(12); it is started from 08:00 and end 16:00. When I remove this one then slider timing will change.
```

So right now it is containing only by default 08:00 to 16:00 hrs. When I change the date then it will set again 08:00 to 16:00. But I want, When ever I land on this page then It will take current time and take +4hrs and -4hrs. then 8hrs duration slider should draw. For example If I land at  2017 31 Jul 08:00 then slider should fill from 2017 31 Jul 04:00 to 2017 31 Jul 12:00. Right now It always same filling(Draw). I tried more but I am not able to make flexible this slider with date. Please share your idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  $scope.$watch('dateBirth', function(n, o) {
    var newDay = n || new Date();
    $scope.selectedDate = moment(newDay);
    $scope.selectedDate.hour(moment().hour());
    $scope.selectedDate.minute(0);
    $scope.init();
  });
  
  $scope.init = function() {
    var startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime;
    
    var timeData = getRange($scope.selectedDate);
    $scope.localTime = timeData.currentTime; // actually start of this hour
    
    var arr = timeData.times.map(n => {
      return {
        value: n.value
        //legend: n.value
      };
    });
    
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.slider = {
        minValue: $scope.localTime.clone().subtract(4, "hours").format('YYYY DD MMM HH:mm'),
        maxValue: $scope.localTime.clone().add(4, "hours").format('YYYY DD MMM HH:mm'),
        options: {
          showTicks: true,
          stepsArray: arr,
          draggableRange: true,
        }
      };
    });
  }
  
  $scope.init();
});

function getRange(currentDate) {
  var arr = [];
  var totalHourRange = 32;
  var currentTime = currentDate || moment(); // current date and time using Moment
  
  // set current time to beginning of the hour
  currentTime.minute(0);
  
  // clone date and substract 1/2 total range to get start point
var tmpTime = currentTime.clone();
     //tmpTime.subtract(totalHourRange / 2, 'hours');
     tmpTime.hour(0).subtract(4, 'hours');
  
  // offset is the number of minutes from the current point
  for (var i = -6 * (totalHourRange / 2); i <= 6 * (totalHourRange / 2); i++) {
      arr.push({value: tmpTime.format('YYYY DD MMM HH:mm'), offset: i * 10});
      tmpTime.add(10, 'minutes');
    }
  return { times: arr, currentTime: currentTime, totalHourRange: totalHourRange };
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="rzSliderDemo">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h2>AngularJS Touch Slider</h2>
    </header>
    <article>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="choos-birth" class="control-label">choose date:</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input id="choos-birth" class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="dateBirth" style="witdh:100px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <h4>Local time (beginning of the hour): <em>{{localTime.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a')}}</em></h4>
      <br /> Model:
      <input type="text" ng-model="slider.minValue" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="slider.maxValue" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.minValue" rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue" rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
Because of this middleDay.setHours(12); it is started from 08:00 and end 16:00. When I remove this one then slider timing will change.
```

Comment: @ K Scandrett. Slider timing is changed.. It should be start 20:00,20:10.....23:50,00.00,00:10,...........23:50, 00:00,....04:00.

Comment: @K Scandrett. Please see my above running example. for plotted timing with date. It containing 3 day. Current date 24 hrs, Previous day 4hrs and next date 4hrs.

Comment: I copied the above code. If you want to do that I told you how in the comments of your original post

Comment: @K Scandrett. Yes. But in your example your date end limit is 12:00. and Start :04:00.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the `tmpTime.hour(0).subtract(4, 'hours');` from original post comments. Is that the functionality you are looking for?

Comment: ... it will always start the day before at 8pm and finish the next day at 4am now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150635/discussion-between-v-sh-and-k-scandrett).

Comment: @K Scandrett. If I changed the slider after that change the date then it will possible slider don't change? Because right I am drag the slider and after that change the date then slider automatically goto previous position.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you further, it requires too much of my time. But here's my latest attempt (not working of course) https://jsfiddle.net/wxt6v4p0/

Comment: If It will possible then It is very helpful for me. You helped me more. Thanks

Comment: @K Scandrett. Please this link If you have some time. My request to you. I am stuck in very bad condition I have pressure because of this..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429746/dont-lose-previous-position-of-rzslider-after-select-the-date-in-angular-js

Comment: I don't have the time, sorry

Comment: @K Scandrett. Its ok. But thanks what ever you gave me solution .