# Don't lose previous position of Rzslider after select the date in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date

I am using RZslider for the date and picker. But I am facing some problem again and agin. And also new in Rzlider and angularJs. So Slider containing 8hrs of current time +4hrs and -4hrs. If  I am run the slider then it containing current time and -4, +4, Example If current time is 10:00 then slider filles 06:00 to 14:00.

**Screen Shot:**
[image]
Then If I change the slider Like drag and after select the date then slider again comes default current value. But I don't want to change slider position after select the date. Because if I change the slider and select the date then I will click one apply button then I will get start date, time and end date, time.

```js
var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  $scope.$watch('dateBirth', function(n, o) {
    var newDay = n || new Date();
    $scope.selectedDate = moment(newDay);
    $scope.selectedDate.hour(moment().hour());
    $scope.selectedDate.minute(0);
    $scope.init();
  });
  
  $scope.init = function() {
    var startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime;
    
    var timeData = getRange($scope.selectedDate);
    $scope.localTime = timeData.currentTime; // actually start of this hour
    
    var arr = timeData.times.map(n => {
      return {
        value: n.value
        //legend: n.value
      };
    });
    
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.slider = {
        minValue: $scope.localTime.clone().subtract(4, "hours").format('YYYY DD MMM HH:mm'),
        maxValue: $scope.localTime.clone().add(4, "hours").format('YYYY DD MMM HH:mm'),
        options: {
          showTicks: true,
          stepsArray: arr,
          draggableRange: true,
        }
      };
    });
  }
  
  $scope.init();
});

function getRange(currentDate) {
  var arr = [];
  var totalHourRange = 32;
  var currentTime = currentDate || moment(); // current date and time using Moment
  
  // set current time to beginning of the hour
  currentTime.minute(0);
  
  // clone date and substract 1/2 total range to get start point
var tmpTime = currentTime.clone();
     //tmpTime.subtract(totalHourRange / 2, 'hours');
     tmpTime.hour(0).subtract(4, 'hours');
  
  // offset is the number of minutes from the current point
  for (var i = -6 * (totalHourRange / 2); i <= 6 * (totalHourRange / 2); i++) {
      arr.push({value: tmpTime.format('YYYY DD MMM HH:mm'), offset: i * 10});
      tmpTime.add(10, 'minutes');
    }
  return { times: arr, currentTime: currentTime, totalHourRange: totalHourRange };
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="rzSliderDemo">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h2>AngularJS Touch Slider</h2>
    </header>
    <article>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="choos-birth" class="control-label">choose date:</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input id="choos-birth" class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="dateBirth" style="witdh:100px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <br />
      <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.minValue" rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue" rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

So If I run the demo then I change the slider position after that select the other date then slider goto previous position(default position as per current time). So I don't want to reset slider value after select the value.

Comment: Do you mean that with the slider you pick time (10:00 for example), then you change the date in the datepicker, then the slider point to 11:00 again and you want that the slider will stay in 10:00 but with the new date?

Comment: @Mosh Feu  .Yes , I want to set date with dragged slider.

Comment: @MoshFeu. I will explain. If I run the example. And drag the slider and point different time. After that If I select the date then slider go to previous position based on default time. But I want if I drag the slider and select the date then Slider don't go to previous position.

Comment: Hi, Angular Slider maintainer here: I would be happy to help but your issue description is really not clear. Could you try to reformulate and provide a reproducing scenario of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ValentinH Yes sure.  I am configuring date or RZSlider for the date and time picker. SO when you change the date the you can see in demo example some legend date also will changing after change the date, So it is working fine. But I change the slider position(for pick time) then select the date after that slider go to previous position. I don't want to chnage slider value autometically. It should be selected by manual. If You have any query please let me know. This is important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is to store the `maxValue` and `minValue` hours. Then when the date change, combine the new date with the old hours (if exist).

```js
var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  $scope.$watch('dateBirth', function(n, o) {
    var newDay = n || new Date();
    $scope.selectedDate = moment(newDay);
    $scope.selectedDate.hour(moment().hour());
    $scope.selectedDate.minute(0);
    $scope.init();
  });
  
  $scope.init = function() {
    var startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime;
    
    var timeData = getRange($scope.selectedDate);
    $scope.localTime = timeData.currentTime; // actually start of this hour
    
    var arr = timeData.times.map(n => {
      return {
        value: n.value
        //legend: n.value
      };
    });
    
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.slider = {
        minValue: $scope.getValue($scope.valueTypes.MIN),
        maxValue: $scope.getValue($scope.valueTypes.MAX),
        options: {
          stepsArray: arr,
          showTicks: true,
          draggableRange: true,
          onChange: function() {
            $scope.minValueHour = moment($scope.slider.minValue).get('hour');
            $scope.maxValueHour = moment($scope.slider.maxValue).get('hour');
          }
        }
      };
    });
  }
  
  $scope.valueTypes = {
    MIN: 'min',
    MAX: 'max'
  };
  
  $scope.getValue = function(kind) {
    var localTime = $scope.localTime.clone();
    
    if ($scope[kind + 'ValueHour']) {
      localTime.set({hour: $scope[kind + 'ValueHour']});
    }
    else {
      var method = kind === 'min' ? 'subtract' : 'add';
      localTime[method](4, "hours")
    }
    
    return localTime.format('YYYY DD MMM HH:mm');
  }
  
  $scope.init();
});

function getRange(currentDate) {
  var arr = [];
  var totalHourRange = 32;
  var currentTime = currentDate || moment(); // current date and time using Moment
  
  // set current time to beginning of the hour
  currentTime.minute(0);
  
  // clone date and substract 1/2 total range to get start point
var tmpTime = currentTime.clone();
     //tmpTime.subtract(totalHourRange / 2, 'hours');
     tmpTime.hour(0).subtract(4, 'hours');
  
  // offset is the number of minutes from the current point
  for (var i = -6 * (totalHourRange / 2); i <= 6 * (totalHourRange / 2); i++) {
    arr.push({value: tmpTime.format('YYYY DD MMM HH:mm'), offset: i * 10});
    tmpTime.add(10, 'minutes');
  }
  return { times: arr, currentTime: currentTime, totalHourRange: totalHourRange };
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="rzSliderDemo">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h2>AngularJS Touch Slider</h2>
    </header>
    <article>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="choos-birth" class="control-label">choose date:</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input id="choos-birth" class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="dateBirth" style="witdh:100px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <br />
      <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.minValue" rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue" rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/zenaco/edit?html,js